# Structured Data Testing Tool throwing error "Missing '}' or object member name."

Tags: json-ld

I am continuously getting the following error:

> Missing '}' or object member name.

Does anyone see what it is referring to? I am not missing the ending `}`.

```json
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ProfessionalService",
        "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Web_design",
        "name": "site",
        "url": "example.com",
        "logo": "example.png",
        "description": "Company",
        "telephone": "555 555 5555",
        "areaServed": ["Canton", "Akron", "Fairlawn", " Medina", "Hudson", "Green", "Cleveland", "Massillon", "Independence", "Stow", "North Canton", "Baberton"],
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the last comma before the '}'. See the second example [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data). Note that you can also whittle these problems down by removing data and retesting.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to add that as an answer below and accept it when you can to complete the question and make it clearer to others what worked. You'll receive some more reputation here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan provided a suggestion that ended up working. I removed the last comma from the areaServed parameter. This resolved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I have got another solution for this:  Please check `ImageObject`, if that's not found then the error could occur.

For example:

```
"image":{
                "@type":"ImageObject",
                "url":"xyz.jpg",
                "width":"830",
                "height": "553"
                }
```